# Incremental copy of log file content

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-transfer, smb, robocopy

I have a couple of log-files, growing one line at a time, as log files do.
The files are available via SMB network share.

**I want to** periodically copy these files. Since the network is rather slow and congested, I do not want to transfer the whole files each time, but only the new lines, that were added after the previous copy.

- I can trust the programs that generate the logs to only ever append to the end of the file. (And if parts of the log files somehow were modified after writing, the entire log would be untrustworthy and useless anyway). It is not required to compare the beginning of the source and target files.
- The source files, and the target folder are only available via SMB file share, no other communication channel between the two systems is allowed.
- The pc running the copy task can access both the source file share as well as the target file share, but both shares are in different networks, and this pc is the only bridge between them.

**Is there** a clever combination of robocopy, xcopy, or other windows commands to accomplish this? Robocopy can resume partial downloads, but I could not get it to work in this case.

I have read that a RSync server would be helpful here, but the communication must cross multiple corporate firewalls blocking everything except smb file share, and the device that generates the logs should not be modified, so I do not think that is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 come with:

```
curl.exe file:////thedevice/sharename/input.log -o \\target\logs\output.log -C -
```

The `-C` option [resumes transfer at a specified byte position](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287431/continue-interrupted-curl-download). Note that it does not *skip* unwanted data – it *seeks to* the wanted starting position, so that the preceding data is never read. For HTTP this means using a Range request; for direct filesystem access it literally means a seek() operation.

Any other tools which implement direct file operations would work as well, e.g. PowerShell using `[System.IO.File]::Open()`, or Python if you can have that installed in the middle machine (this is for demonstration purposes only):

```python
source = r"\\thedevice\sharename\input.log"
target = r"\\target\logs\output.log"

with open(source, "rb") as srcf:
    with open(target, "ab") as dstf:
        last_pos = dstf.tell()
        print("Restarting at byte", last_pos)
        srcf.seek(last_pos)
        while buf := srcf.read(1*1024*1024):
            dstf.write(buf)
        print("Copied", srcf.tell() - last_pos, "bytes")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to compare old and new logs and copy only the new lines,
but this would be sort of self-defeating.

The compare operation itself will need to read the network file,
which is entirely equivalent to copying it.
You will not gain any performance.

You may perhaps be able to parameter the remote computer to frequently
start a new logfile, or copy the file only in times of non-congestion,
or even zip the file on the remote computer before transferring
in order to reduce it. There aren't too many solutions to this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify my question. Comparing is not necessary: The files are only ever appended, so the file size of the old file is enough to know where to continue. I can trust the logging application to only append at the end, and if the file were to be be modified in another way, the whole log would be corrupt anyway. The trouble is, I believe robocopy could resume a partial copy, but will not do so if the time stamps differ.

Comment: You may need to either write a PowerShell script to read the network file starting from the end of the old file, or use a Linux/WSL program `tail -c +[previous size]` to start at a specific byte offset of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The target log file has the latest detail in it copied from the source log. Get the line count value from your target log and then use that number when you read from the source log to skip that number of lines when it reads it. Append what's there after that line to the target log file.

The PowerShell example below uses [get-content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2) piped over to [select-object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) using the `-skip` parameter with the number value based on the copy log current line count,then it pipes that over to [add-content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2) to append the new log file data as preferred.

### PowerShell

```
$targetFile = "\\tserver\tshare\tfolder\CopyLog.txt";
$sourceFile = "\\sserver\sshare\sfolder\xyz.txt";
$tFLC = (Get-Content $targetFile).Count;
(Get-Content $sourceFile | Select-Object -Skip $tFLC) | Add-Content $targetFile;
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2)
- [Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2)

  > `-Skip`
  >
  > ***Skips (does not select) the specified number of items.*** By default, the
  > Skip parameter counts from the beginning of the array or list of
  > objects, but if the command uses the Last parameter, it counts from
  > the end of the list or array.
  >
  > Unlike the Index parameter, which starts counting at 0, the Skip
  > parameter begins at 1.
- [Add-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: But the `(Get-Content $targetFile).Count` still needs to transfer the whole file in order to count the number of lines within, and the `(Get-Content $sourceFile | Select-Object -Skip $tFLC)` still needs to provide actual objects for Select-Object to skip through, which again means reading all of the initial lines.

Comment: @HugoRune True, I guess you would have to get a bit more innovative and complex with the logic because this does have to read each line thus defeating the purpose. You'd have to have a way to trigger the source server based on some SMB file you drop to do a line count on that side, and then use that number to create a temp file to run this logic on it's side, drop just that data to a different file, and that file would be the one to sync up and append with similar logic as I added here. All trivial but a tad more complex and there'd be a controlled trigger, wait, then sync type deal.

Comment: @HugoRune This does assume the target UNC is fast and you'd do a line count of it using the `-ReadCount` parameter optimizing memory, then SMB a file named `count.txt` with that value in line one only to the source UNC, a process on that side would see that file, and then create a temp file of everything in the log to `new.txt` and then it'd delete `count.txt` and then you'd run the logic to get-content from new.txt, append it to the target/destination log, then delete new.txt. Trigger again on next run and automate something on the source side to trigger every x minutes when count.txt exist.